# vb.net What do I need to import to use textrange?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use

following code to change richtextbox content to text like.

```
Dim tr As New TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd)

documentText = tr

        Dim titleMatch As Match = Regex.Match(documentText, expression, options)
```

But it says Type 'TextRange' is not defined.
Any advice, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `System.Windows.Documents`.

You can see this by looking at the [documentation for TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.aspx):

> Namespace:  System.Windows.Documents
>
> Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Comment: It seems that I need to add reference to use it. Could you tell me which one?

Comment: @user1785594 `PresentationFramework` - Again, its in the docs ("Assembly" is the reference  you need)